# AWS - deleting IAM users. What is "user data"?

Tags: amazon-web-services

In our company's AWS account there are user accounts belonging to staff, many of which left the company some years ago.

When I go to delete these accounts, I am presented with the following warning:

> The following users will be permanently deleted, including all user data, user security credentials, and user inline policies. Deleted user data cannot be recovered. Are you sure that you want to delete the following users?

I understand security credentials and user inline policies, but I am worried about what is covered by "**all user data**". We have a lot of data in S3 which I do not want deleted.

After searching and reading documentation, I can't find any indication of what else "all user" data encompasses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your buckets will be left in place.  Buckets and the objects in them are always owned by the account, not by any specific user of the account, regardless of which user created the buckets or the objects.

"User data" only refers to data about the user's account.

See [Deleting an IAM User](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_users_manage.html#id_users_deleting) in the IAM User Guide.